# Is there a bitwise equivalent to [].pop()?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I need to iterate through a bitmap, starting with the smallest bit.

On the first loop, I need to check the smallest bit, then the second smallest. So if my value is `6`, I get `false, true, true`.

I'd like to write code that looks like this:

```
if (bitmap.pop()){
```

But that's not an option. What's an *elegant* alternative?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: `(6).toString(2).split('').reverse().map(function(i) { return i === '1'; });` ?

Comment: @zerkms awesome, though you might want to use `=== '1'` instead so there's no deluding yourself that you're iterating over the digits of a number as strings `:P`

Comment: How is your bit array data structure organized? You should be able to use simple bit masking ie. `v & 1` operation to extract the last bit. If you have only a single integer then you can just `>>` the value to pop out the first bit. If you have arbitrary length bit array then you'd have to keep track of the number of bits left in the last item.

Comment: @zeroes That's kind of what I was thinking. `toString(2).split('')` and then pop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bitwise operators, this should work:

```
var a = 6;

do {
    if (a & 1) {
        // true
    } else {
        // false
    }
} while (a = a >> 1);
```

If you do not want to use the classical way and need a pop() like function you could use a prototype object which defines a pop() function, like this one:

```
function PopNumbers (startNumber) {
    this.startNumber = startNumber;
}

PopNumbers.prototype.hasNext = function () {
    return (this.nextNumber === undefined || this.nextNumber !== 0);
};

PopNumbers.prototype.pop = function () {
    if (this.hasNext()) {
            var currentNumber = this.nextNumber || this.startNumber;
            this.nextNumber = currentNumber >> 1;
            return !!(currentNumber & 1);
    }
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pascalockert/JHM2f/

Comment: Well, this is the classic way. But it seems like I'll stick with this.

Comment: I added a non-classic way ;) It uses an additional prototype object and should match your requirements

Answer (score 1):

Efficiently: use [bit twiddling.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Less-efficiently: put the 0s and 1s of the binary representation of your number into an array, and use `Array.pop()`, [as @zerkms suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275775/is-there-a-bitwise-equivalent-to-pop/21275820#comment32058157_21275775).

Answer (score 0):

What are your criteria for "elegant"? Maybe:

```
function flipBits(x) {
  var arr = [];
  do {
    arr.push(!!(x % 2));
  } while (x = x >> 1)
  return arr;
}

alert(flipBits(6)) // false, true, true
alert(flipBits(7)) // true, true, true
alert(flipBits(7)) // true, true, false, true, true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `&1` operation to extract the last bit. Now, to shift the bits you can simply use the `>>` operator on the last item. To avoid having to shift values in all the entries we can simply keep track of the number of bits left in the last integer.

Here is an example that assumes that you have your least significant bit in the last integer of the bit array and that you use 32 bits per entry.

```
var values = [0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffff01];

var lsbSize = 32;

function pop() {
    var value = values[values.length-1] & 1; // extract last bit
    value = value?true:false;
    values[values.length-1] = values[values.length-1] >> 1; // shift out the last bit in the last entry
    lsbSize--;
    if(lsbSize == 0) { // if there are no more bits left in the last entry. simply pop it out and reset the size
        values.pop();
        lsbSize = 32;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LJFr7/1/)